# How to make a delete query in design view

Tags: ms-access

please supply me with the correct SQL in order to delete all records from the table "SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE" where "[SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE].[PART_ID]" equals "[tblPartsWithBadDefaultPrice].[PART_ID]" and where SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE.DISCOUNT_CODE equals "STANDARD".

thank you very  much and happy holidays!

DELETE SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE.DISCOUNT_CODE, SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE.PART_ID
FROM SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE INNER JOIN tblPartsWithBadDefaultPrice ON SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE.PART_ID = tblPartsWithBadDefaultPrice.PART_ID
WHERE (((SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE.DISCOUNT_CODE)="STANDARD") AND ((SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE.PART_ID)=[tblPartsWithBadDefaultPrice].[PART_ID]));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about "MS Access Design View", but this is the SQL you need:

```
DELETE FROM 
  SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE
WHERE 
  PART_ID IN (SELECT PART_ID FROM tblPartsWithBadDefaultPrice) AND
  DISCOUNT_CODE = "STANDARD"
```